# Cordova/Phonegap stops firing when html is removed

Tags: cordova

I am using Cordova and I've run into a very strange issue.

I've added alerts to my index.js file just to let me know that onDeviceReady has been fired.

It all works great until I remove this code from the html page:

```
<div class="app">
<h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
<div id="deviceready" class="blink">
<p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
<p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the code for the index.js:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        alert('I am ready');


    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Has anyone had this issue before? How can I sort it out?

Comment: cordova.js file  have issue,try to replace

Comment: Could you please post some more of you code? Do you have any javascript errors? Maybe you still have a reference to the element with id="deviceready" ?

Comment: OK, I've added the index.js code

Comment: you remove the html with some ids, then you do a document.getElementById(id);, but the id doesn't exists anymore, so you are getting javascript errors and app doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line

```
var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
```

you are fetching the div with the class *listening*. Then after that you are trying to set attribute for that non-existing div at

```
listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
```

This causes an exception and the execution never continues until your alert.